# C# recursion with disposable parameter and async await

Tags: c#, recursion, async-await, task-parallel-library

Is it safe to call a async method recursively if the method contains parameters that need to be disposed?

```
public async Task<bool> ConnectAsync(CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource)
{
    using CancellationTokenSource token = new CancellationTokenSource();
    await ConnectAsync(token).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: yes, but are you sure that code works?, I feel that you will deal with an infinite recursion.

Comment: yes, the code shows just the recursive part of the method and it's supposed to run infinitely.

Comment: Or do you mean recursion in general is not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is safe in that control will always return back to the instance of the method that created it. So as long as you:

1. Use a `using` statement or call `Dispose()` manually, and
2. `await` the call

Then the object will get disposed properly, and not before it's used.

However, as with all recursion, you need to be careful not to end up in a [stack overflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stackoverflowexception?view=netframework-4.8). That method, exactly as you have written it, will end up in a stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in C# recursion with using statement is safe, the object will be disposed properly when the execution of the callee terminates and code gets back to the caller.

But as I understand you want an infinite recursion, in that case that object will never be disposed, not because your code is unsafe, simply it is not possible to dispose that object.

Anyway, the problem there is that you can't do infinite recursion, soon or after you will deal with a stack overflow, c# doesn't support tail optimization, so infinite recursion is not supported in C#.

Comment: Makes sense. Ok, so it's not completely infinite. At some point it may exit the recursion, but it's not guaranteed. So I guess in this case it's not safe to use recursion. But could I dispose the objects after n recursive calls to avoid the problems you mentioned?

Comment: if at some point you exit, it is safe, simply it can't be infinite

Comment: I don't think you need bother about if this code is safe or not, you will go into into a stack overflow.
If you need to dispose after n calls depends on the needs of your application, it has no sense to dispose it if you still need it for an indefinite amount of time.